# Scaling a PDF page using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm trying to convert PDF pages to `BufferedImage` instances using the Apache PDFBox library. Why is the following code not working?

```
try {
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);  // pdfFile is file path to pdf
    List<PDPage> pgeLst = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();

    for(PDPage pge : pgeLst) {
        final PDRectangle mediaBox = pge.getMediaBox();
        mediaBox.setUpperRightX(mediaBox.getUpperRightX() * scale);
        mediaBox.setUpperRightY(mediaBox.getUpperRightY() * scale);

        BufferedImage img = page.convertToImage();  // Image should now be scaled,
                                                    // but isn't.
    }

} catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Maybe the solution is very easy, though I searched the web and the JavaDoc and didn't find any solution.

I'm using PDFBox version 1.8.8, precisely `pdfbox-app-1.8.8.jar`.
Thank you Tilman Hausherr for pointing that out :)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Regardless if my answer is good - please enter the PDFBox version in your question, this will be helpful for people in the future :-) The current version is 1.8.7, 1.8.8 will come out within hours.

Comment: As an aside... your original code made no difference because you did not set the page media box to the changed rectangle (using `PDPage.setMediaBox`). And if you had updated the page media box, the effect would not have been the desired one because you do not scale the page content but merely the canvas on which it is drawn, and depending on the original choice of mediabox coordinates you do not even scale it as desired.

Comment: I tried using setMediaBox as well. And it also didnt affect the rendering of the image in any way. It just scaled nothing. Now i see why :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
BufferedImage img = page.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 300);
```

in PDFBox 1.8.*, this will render at 300dpi. The default (which you used) is 144dpi. So use a dpi parameter that is larger or smaller than 144 depending on what you want.

Comment: I see, i guess i was just confused by the javadoc, as i overlooked the default value of 144dpi. Now it makes sense. Thank you :)